# Панель окон в MDI-интерфейсе

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Как сделать панель открытых окон в MDI-форме, похожий на IBExpert:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно, вам подойдёт [AvalonDock](http://avalondock.codeplex.com/documentation).

Comment: А штатными средствами? Тем более я пишу на WinForms

Comment: (1) Если вам нужен сложный интерфейс, переходите на WPF. WinForms даёт вам только стандартные нативные контролы.   
(2) Штатными средствами придётся изобретать много велосипедов.  
(3) Хотя, попробуйте `TabControl` в WPF, может, этого вам окажется достаточно.

Comment: Как я не старался освоить WPF не нравится он мне, да и сам метод строения интерфейса меня вообще вводит в ужас.

Comment: Что ж, воля ваша. Писать вручную layout manager — непростая, но увлекательная задача, удачи вам! (Кстати, в WPF можно и не пользоваться дизайнером, а верстать XAML вручную.)

Comment: делали же раньше люди без WPF и вполне успешно, почему же на сегодняшний день это должно быть как то неимоверно сложно.

Comment: Да, делали :-) Я тоже как-то писал похожую на WPF систему (только попроще) на чистом C++. Всё можно сделать, вопрос во времени и затратах труда.

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой вариант, пожалуй, взять исходили .net и вытащить то, как мелкомягкие формируют MdiWindowListItem.

Вообще, лично мне много пришлось с этим чудом работать и, скажу честно, без рефлексии там ничего не добьешься. Ну и WinAPI кое-где приходится применять.

Comment: Это явно самый простой способ.